# Javascript code execution order

Tags: javascript, google-maps

just wondering if someone can help me with a Javascript principle.  I'm guessing this is pretty core if I want to pass a function as a parameter.  I know a little about Javascript but I admit possibly not enough about its subtleties.

So, codeAddress is invoked, then my first alert (HERE2) is reached, code passes back to my showOnMap function, then my second alert (HERE3) is reached.  Why does my HERE3 alert show before my HERE2 alert?  Is there anything I can do to tell Javascript to wait?

Thanks in advance

```
function showOnMap() {
    var inputStart = document.getElementById('CurrentHitch_StartDescription').value;
    var inputEnd = document.getElementById('CurrentHitch_EndDescription').value;
    codeAddress(inputStart, true); //HERE1*************
    codeAddress(inputEnd, false);
    var bounds2 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(this.markerStart.getPosition());
    bounds2.extend(this.markerEnd.getPosition());
    map.fitBounds(bounds2);
    alert('showOnMap'); //HERE3*************
}

function codeAddress(address, isStart) {
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        alert('codeAddress'); //HERE2*************
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (isStart) {
                markerStart.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
            }
            else {
                markerEnd.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
            }
        } else {
            alert("Sorry, couldn't find your destination: " + status);
        }
    });
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `geocode` is happening asynchronously (**non**-blocking code, meaning sometime in the future, and I'll let you know when I'm done). It *might* be possible to tell Google's api to work synchronously (as blocking code), but you'd probably be better off putting code that depends on the results in the callback of `geocode`.

Comment: It's really tricky. I've been struggling with this same issue, and I didn't find a solution....

Comment: Thanks, yup, I'm passing my code into the callback functionality and it's doing as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the `ajax` world...
`geocode` is an ajax service provided by google.

You send an **async** request, you are not waiting for it to return, continue with the code, The "third" alert fires, the async request comes back, you fire the "second" alert.

Think about this code:

```
alert('1');
setTimeout(function(){ 
    alert('2');
}, 1000); // fire the function after one second.
alert('3');
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/2272Q/)

Output order:

> 1,3,2